# Making conditions for a random name generator

Tags: c++

I'm working on making a random name generator, and I'm trying to add conditions like, "if the previous letter is a 'c', there is a percentage chance that the next letter will be an 'h'." For testing purposes, I made the chance 100% to see if the code worked, but I still get instances where some c's are not followed by an h. My code so far is this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < randomLength; ++i) 
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        if (startsWithVowel)//startsWithVowel is true
            //frist letter is a random vowel
            randomName += vowels[rand() % 5];
        else
            //frist letter is a random consonant
            randomName += consonants[rand() % 21];
    }
    else
    {
        if (randomName[i-1] == 'c')
        {
            /*chance = rand() % 100 + 1;
            if (chance < 31)*/
            randomName += 'h';
        }
        else
        {
            chance = rand() % 100 + 1;
            if (chance < 51)
                randomName += vowels[rand() % 5];
            randomName += consonants[rand() % 21];
        }
    }
```

randomName is an array of characters and the arrays vowels and consonants hold the vowels and consonants respectively of the english language.

Comment: Rather than a rule-based approach, which will be complicated to flesh out, consider a Machine Learning approach, where you can take a list of names and compute the likelihood that letter "q" will be followed by "r", or "s", or...

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: your code would be more testable if you would use a function `char nextLetter(char previousLetter)`. Then `nextLetter('c')` wouldnt involve any randomness and would be simpler to be verified for correctness

Comment: At the bottom of your code, `randomName` is incremented without adjusting `i`.

Comment: I am pretty sure `randomName` is NOT "an array of characters", because `+=` wouldn't work with an array.  Looks like you are using `string` (which is killing performance, you should be using `StringBuilder` and calling `Append` not `+=`!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this block:

```
if (chance < 51)
    randomName += vowels[rand() % 5];
randomName += consonants[rand() % 21];
```

if `chance` was less than `51` - the vowel was appended. If the next letter was randomly chosen to be `c` - it won't be caught by the

```
if (randomName[i-1] == 'c')
```

check because i was not properly incremented and points to a vowel